# Abstract class with Custom Annotations

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

First, I am pretty new to Java reflection, generics and annotations.

I would like to develop an abstract class that would allow me to support a various set of POJOs ([value objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) to be more accurate) by providing generic implementations/methods based on custom annotations from the child class.

**Abstract Class**

```
public abstract class AbstractValueObject<T>

    private Class<T> targetClass;
    private Integer id;
    private String rowState;

    public AbstractValueObject(final Class<T> targetClassToSet) {

        this.targetClass = targetClassToSet;

        for (Method method : targetClass.getMethods()) {

            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(ValueObjectId.class)) {
                ... invoke getter that has the @ValueObjectId annotation from the child class, and set that value in the id class attribute...
            }

            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(ValueObjectRowState.class)) {
                ... invoke getter that has the @ValueObjectRowState annotation from the child classfro, and set that value in the rowState class attribute...
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isNew() {
    ... logic based on id and rowState ...
    }

    public boolean isUpdated() {
    ... logic based on id and rowState ...
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
    ... logic based on id and rowState ...
    }

    abstract boolean isValid();
}
```

**Example child class**

```
public class MyCustomClass extends AbstractValueObject<MyCustomClass> implements Serializable {

   private String fileId;
   private String fileRowState;

   @ValueObjectId
   public String getFileId() {
       return fileId;
   }

   public void setFileId(String fileId) {
       this.fileId = fileId;
   }

   @ValueObjectRowState
   public String getFileRowState() {
       return fileRowState
   }

   public void setFileRowState(String fileRowState) {
       this.fileRowState= fileRowState;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isValid() {
   ...specific implementation...
   }
}
```

**Annotations**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ValueObjectId {
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ValueObjectRowState {
}
```

Is it feasible? I haven't found any example similar to this requirement yet.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to do this exactly?

Comment: Because in fact the algorithm for isAdded, isUpdated and isDeleted is always about the same two class variables (id and row state). One MyCustomClass instance represents a line in my view. Each line can be added (meaning it must be persisted), updated, meaning it must update the existing record), deleted (remove the entity) or none (existing but not changed). It is just a matter of reusing as much code as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost everything should work in this way, however:

You want to call a getter on the wrapped object. But you only pass the class of the object as parameter. If your approach should work, you will have to give the object as parameter.

Note that reflection is not very performant, especially if applied to many objects. Your approach will have to compute it every time a new object is passed to a constructor of `AbstractValueObject`, caching the reflective information (Method, MethodHandle) would make it faster.

If you know all classes of objects that satisfy a value object (and you do not plan to introduce new classes at runtime), than a visitor pattern would be more suitable and more performant.

Comment: Will definitely look for the visitor pattern. Thank you.